# Are past participles in -thed ever pronounced -ðid?

Tags: pronunciation

Do native speakers ever (erroneously) pronounce past participles in *-thed*, such as bathed and clothed, as */-ðɪd/ rather than /-ðd/?  If so, how prevalent is this?

Answer (score 1):

In Modern English, a big **No**. In Old English and Middle English, Yes!

The past/past participles of regular verbs were all pronounced /-ɪd/ (or maybe /-ɨd/) until Modern English. As far as I know, Shakespeare has used both forms (/-ɪd/ and /-d/), but the vowel was then lost and the final /d/ merged into the preceding consonant. That's why we say /beɪðd/ not */beɪðɪd/.

Comment: Some non-verbs ending in *-ed* do have the /-ɪd/ sound though, e.g. *crooked* and *wicked*.

Answer (score 0):

I can’t recall hearing a native speaker make that mistake, at least past the young age when we first learn that sound, but it is sometimes done on purpose in poetry or lyrics (and written as bath’ed or bath-ed) when the author needs an extra syllable to fit the meter or rhythm.